# Material UI InputAdornment icon placement is outside the input area of TextField

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, textfield

I can't figure out how my InputAdornment is getting improperly placed.

I can't see anything in my styles that would influence the position of the icon within the TextField (e.g. padding, flex stuff).

How it currently looks - calendar does not sit on the line/within text field input

[image: How the TextField looks - notice the calendar icon does not sit on the line]

How I would like it to look - but of course with a calendar icon and not a 'kg' :)

[image]

My styles object (with some ... used for brevity)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    input: {
        '& input, textarea': {
            paddingTop: 8,
            paddingBottom: 12,
            fontSize: 15,
            marginTop: 15,
            '&:focus': {
                borderBottomColor: COLORS.BLACK
            },
            '&::placeholder': {
                fontSize: 15
            }
        },
    },
    ...
    dashboardInput: {
        '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
            color: theme.palette.text.primary,
            fontSize: 16,
        },
        '& input, textarea': {
            borderBottom: `1px solid ${COLORS.BLACK}`,
            fontSize: 16,
            '&::placeholder': {
                color: theme.palette.grey[400],
            },
            '&:disabled': {
                color: COLORS.BLACK
            }
        },
        '& .MuiFormHelperText-root': {
            color: theme.palette.grey[500],
            fontSize: 10
        },
    },
   ...
    inputLimiter: {
        textAlign: 'right',
        fontSize: 10
    },
    ...
    },
}));
```

The relevant guts of the component:

```
    <FormControl
        fullWidth
        className={classNames(classes.input, getInputStyle(appearance), {
            [classes.error]: error
        })}
    >
        <InputLabel shrink htmlFor={name}>
            <div className={classes.divcontrol}><div>{label}</div><div className={classes.redAsterisk}>*</div></div>
        </InputLabel>
        <TextField
            id={name}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            fullWidth
            multiline={multiline}
            rows={multiline ? rows : 0}
            type={type}
            style={style}
            inputProps={{
                maxLength,
            }}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            disabled={disabled}
            onChange={e => onChangeWithRightType(e)}
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
            }}
            value={value}
            {...props}
            InputProps={{
                disableUnderline: true,
                endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <DateRange />
                    </InputAdornment>
                ),
            }}
            error
            helperText={helperText}
        />
        {maxLength && (
            <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.inputLimiter}>
                {value ? String(value).length : 0}/{maxLength}
            </Typography>
        )}
    </FormControl>
```

[image: How I would like the TextField to look - I just grabbed a sample from the MUI docs, so it says 'kg' and is not a calendar icon, but you get the idea...I want my icon to sit on the line :)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question, I think you should set disableUnderline in InputProps to false.

```js
InputProps={{
              disableUnderline: false,
              ......
           }}
```

Comment: As is almost always expected, this opened up a can of worms of new problems, but was definitely part of the solution! thanks!